# Lilypond: temporarily disable grace notes synchronization over staves

Tags: lilypond

In a piano score, is it possible to have grace notes *not* being 'synchronized' to the other staff?

I know there is `\override Score.SpacingSpanner.strict-grace-spacing = ##t`, but this applies to the whole score. I need it only for some parts. (Note: `\override Score.SpacingSpanner.strict-grace-spacing = ##f` seems to be ignored, once `= ##t` has been seen.)

```
\version "2.19.84"
\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff \relative c'{
      \key e \major \time 4/4
      #(define afterGraceFraction (cons 8 9))
      \override Score.SpacingSpanner.strict-grace-spacing = ##t
      gis''2-2 \afterGrace ais\startTrillSpan {gis16( \stopTrillSpan ais)} |
      \afterGrace <bis,, bis'>4\startTrillSpan {ais'16(\stopTrillSpan bis)} <cis, cis'>2.\sf |
      \override Score.SpacingSpanner.strict-grace-spacing = ##f                     % = ##f ignored?
      \grace{b16 gis'} dis'2 \grace{cis,16 fisis} dis'2 |
    }
    \new Staff \relative c{
      \key e \major \time 4/4 \clef bass
      \repeat unfold 2 {dis16 b' gis b} \repeat unfold 2 {dis, cis' fisis, cis'} |
      fis,16 dis' gis, dis' \repeat unfold 3 {e, cis' gis cis} |
      \repeat unfold 2 {gis, gis' dis gis} \repeat unfold 2 {gis, ais' dis, ais'} |
    }
  >>
}
```

With `strict-grace-spacing = ##t`:

[image]

With `strict-grace-spacing = ##f` (or without `strict-grace-spacing`):

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but have you tried adding `\once` before your override?

Comment: Yes, I have – it does not change a thing. I am trying to have the grace note in measure 1 and 2 as they are, and in measure 3, I want the extra space in the lower staff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `\newSpacingSection` command.

```
\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff \relative c'{
      \key e \major \time 4/4
      #(define afterGraceFraction (cons 8 9))
      \override Score.SpacingSpanner.strict-grace-spacing = ##t
      gis''2-2 \afterGrace ais\startTrillSpan {gis16( \stopTrillSpan ais)} |
      \afterGrace <bis,, bis'>4\startTrillSpan {ais'16(\stopTrillSpan bis)} <cis, cis'>2.\sf |
      \newSpacingSection
      \override Score.SpacingSpanner.strict-grace-spacing = ##f
      \grace{b16 gis'} dis'2 \grace{cis,16 fisis} dis'2 |
    }
    \new Staff \relative c{
      \key e \major \time 4/4 \clef bass
      \repeat unfold 2 {dis16 b' gis b} \repeat unfold 2 {dis, cis' fisis, cis'} |
      fis,16 dis' gis, dis' \repeat unfold 3 {e, cis' gis cis} |
      \repeat unfold 2 {gis, gis' dis gis} \repeat unfold 2 {gis, ais' dis, ais'} |
    }
  >>
}
```

Check out here: http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/new-spacing-section

By the way, the new stable version 2.20 has just been released.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the Scheme definition and the two overrides, I that produces what I think you want.

```
\version "2.19.84"
\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff \relative c'{
      \key e \major \time 4/4
      gis''2-2 \afterGrace ais\startTrillSpan {gis16( \stopTrillSpan ais)} |
      \afterGrace <bis,, bis'>4\startTrillSpan {ais'16(\stopTrillSpan bis)} <cis, cis'>2.\sf |
      \grace{b16 gis'} dis'2 \grace{cis,16 fisis} dis'2 |
    }
    \new Staff \relative c{
      \key e \major \time 4/4 \clef bass
      \repeat unfold 2 {dis16 b' gis b} \repeat unfold 2 {dis, cis' fisis, cis'} |
      fis,16 dis' gis, dis' \repeat unfold 3 {e, cis' gis cis} |
      \repeat unfold 2 {gis,16 gis' dis gis} \repeat unfold 2 {gis, ais' dis, ais'}  
    }
  >>
}
```